# What's the process for purchasing a used car in Austria?

Tags: car, austria, car-insurance

Can anyone share more information about the process of buying a car privately in Austria?

My understanding so far is that I have to:

- Pay the seller for the vehicle in return for the documentation and service history, proof of ownership (Auto-Kaufvertrag [example 1](https://www.gebrauchtwagen.at/kfz-kaufvertrag.php) | [example 2](https://www.oeamtc.at/thema/autokauf/oeamtc-kaufvertrag-zur-verwendung-zwischen-privatpersonen-16183846)), and Pickerl (proof of roadworthiness).
- Take this information to the office of a nearby insurer, where I pay tax and insurance in return for obtaining licence plates for the car.
- Return to the car with the plates and collect the keys from the owner.
- If insured fully comprehensive, I then have to get the car inspected at either the ÖAMTC or ARBÖ car clubs, or at the office of the insurer. (Until inspected it appears that insurance is only third-party, or subject to a higher excess.)
- Buy an Autobahn Vignette to use the car on motorways.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding of this correct?
2. If I buy the car in another region, such as Vienna, can I obtain plates in Vienna for another region of Austria? Or do I have to register it in Vienna, then pay extra to re-register the vehicle in my home city?

Answer (score 2):

The parts about buying, insurance, and the Vignette sound fine.  Nothing important to add here imo.

About the check by Öamtc etc.: Not exactly sure about the insurance requirements, but this is strongly recommended anyways - the "Pickerl" checks are not full checks of the car, just some important and/or easily breaking things. Doing it more thorough helps both to know if the car is actually what the seller promised (eg. no accidents that you weren't told about), and, of course, to reduce the risk of dying because some technical problem.

About the different location, the easiest (but unlikely) case would be that you can convince the seller to drive back on his/her registration and insurance, then do everything where you live.
Possibilty 2: Get to Vienna to get to know and to buy the car, come back without car but with the necessary paperwork that you got from the seller, register it where you live, get to Vienna again, and finally drive back with the car.
Possibilty 3 is a temporary 3-week registration (Überstellungskennzeichen) in Vienna which is more expensive than a real registration, and then the real one at home.

Disclaimer: I'm  no car merchant, lawyer, or similar - no guarantees for correctness and/or completeness.